# Why does the free() function affect the value of the first 4 elements of an array?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic

I'm currently learning about dynamic memory allocation in C, and I'm following a tutorial from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/portfoliocourses/c-example-code/main/dynamicmem.c

I've modified the code, like so:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int size = 0;
  printf("Enter size: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);
  int *a = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
  // initialize the array with some values
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) a[i] = size - i;
  // print out the array values
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
  printf("\na: %p\n", a);
  
  a = realloc(a, sizeof(int) * (size + 5));
  // set the additional 2 int values in the array to 9
  for (int i = size; i < (size+2); i++) a[i] = 9;

  for (int i = 0; i < (size+2); i++)
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
  printf("\n");

  int *save = a; 
  free(a); 
  printf("save: %p\n", save);
  for (int i = 0; i < (size+2); i++)
    printf("save[%d] = %d\n", i, save[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

After inputting 5 into the program, the expected output of the "save" pointer should be

```
save[0] = 5
save[1] = 4
save[2] = 3
save[3] = 2
save[4] = 1
save[5] = 9
save[6] = 9
```

However, it instead outputs

```
save[0] = -1397267184
save[1] = 576
save[2] = -1397292720
save[3] = 576
save[4] = 1
save[5] = 9
save[6] = 9
```

The goal of the program is to show how free() makes the memory available again, but not remove the stored data. I'm wondering if it's because I'm using Windows 10, or because of the GCC compiler? I've tried using an online compiler, and a few other Windows 10 systems and they have produced the same result, where save[0] to save[3] outputs arbitrary numbers. Thank you

Comment: It's UB. You don't know that it did or did not change the data. Don't access freed memory, period.

Comment: You have UB: "use after free" Compile with `-fsanitize=address` and run it. It will show the error and where it occurs. Specifically, it flags the `printf` statement inside the loop (that references the data in `save` (i.e. `a`)). Note that `printf` calls [can call] `malloc` [internally] and you did `free(a);` so `malloc` chose [can choose] to reuse the space within `a` because you _told_ it that it could. Doing `int *save = a;` does _not_ fix this issue as they both point to the save (freed) memory locations.

Comment: Your code PRESUMES that `calloc()` has returned an address of a block of memory for your use... How would you feel if other functions read/wrote outside the boundaries of blocks they had allocated and into yours??? (You should ALWAYS test that system functions like `[mc]alloc()` and `fopen()` have succeeded or failed! Even `scanf()` can fail...) Woe betide the code that follows the NULL pointer...

Comment: If the tutorial contains the 'use after free' example and sets expectations about what will be in the data, then you should stop following that tutorial — it is teaching you things that cannot be justified.

Comment: The four "arbitrary numbers" are probably the numeric representation of two 64-bit pointers (each split into two 32-bit `int`s) that form one node of a doubly linked list that tracks all the free memory blocks, so the next time you call `malloc`, it can easily find a chunk of free space of a suitable size.

Comment: The author of that software in the link does not have much clue about what they are talking about. "// we've maintained the pointer to the original block of memory with save..." That comments indicates that `free(a)` might change `a`. That is not the case. Calling a function with a copy of the passed value cannot change the variable in the caller. That `save` variable is totally useless. That goes hand in hand with the attempt to look at memory that doesn't belong to the code any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal of the program is to show how free() makes the memory available again, but not remove the stored data.

That is a false statement about `free`. `free` releases the reservation for the memory at the address passed to it, and that memory is **immediately** available for any use, including use by the memory management routines for keeping track of available blocks of memory. They might or might not write into that memory.

Since your program sets `save` to point to the same place as `a`, passing `a` to `free` means the program may no longer rely on the contents of memory that `save`  points to.

Comment: I see, so there are other factors that may affect the memory. Thank you